# Salesforce trigger addError method to compare date/time fields old and new

Tags: apex

I am creating events on Account object. In the event object I have two date/time fields Start Time and End Time.
My question is how I can validate new Start Time or End Time of an event exists with any  existing event related to an Account?

The only way I can think to validate if the sessions overlap is to use a trigger with the addError() method.
It means new event should not be created on an Account if there is an existing event relays with same date/time.
how can I compare the times of each event for an Account?

here is my trigger I am failing to achieve my requirement. Any one help me appretiated.

trigger sessionValidation on Event (before insert,before update) {

```
Set<ID> accID = new set<ID>();

for(Event eve : trigger.new)
{
  accID.add(eve.AccountId);
}

List<Event> ExistingEventList = [Select StartDateTime , EndDateTime from Event where AccountID in : accID];
system.debug('ExistingEventList :'+ExistingEventList);

for(Event sNew : trigger.new)
{

    for(Event sOld : ExistingEventList)
    {
                        if((sNew.StartDateTime <= sOld.StartDateTime && sNew.EndDateTime  >=  sOld.StartDateTime && sNew.EndDateTime <= sOld.EndDateTime) || 
               (sNew.StartDateTime <= sOld.StartDateTime && sNew.EndDateTime  >= sOld.StartDateTime && sNew.EndDateTime >= sOld.EndDateTime) ||
               )
        {
            sNew.addError('Overlap Session');
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

So it seems as though the `AccountId` field is not populated in the `before` context in a trigger. I put this code together to show a different way:

```
//trigger code
trigger evtTrig on Event (before insert)
{
    Set<ID> accID = new set<ID>();

    for(Event eve : trigger.new)
    {
        if(Schema.Account.SObjectType == eve.WhatId.getSobjectType())
        {
            accID.add(eve.WhatId);
        }
    }

    List<Event> ExistingEventList = [Select StartDateTime , EndDateTime from Event where AccountID in : accID];
    system.debug('ExistingEventList :'+ExistingEventList);

    for(Event sNew : trigger.new)
    {
        for(Event sOld : ExistingEventList)
        {
            DateTime oldStart = sOld.StartDateTime;
            DateTime oldEnd = sOld.EndDateTime;

            DateTime newStart = sNew.StartDateTime;
            DateTime newEnd = sNew.EndDateTime;

            if((newStart >= oldStart && newStart <= oldEnd) || (newEnd >= oldStart && newEnd <= oldEnd))
            {
                sNew.addError('Overlap Session');
            }
        }
    }
}

//Test Method to verify
@isTest
    private static void testMethod4()
    {
        Account a = new Account();
        a.Name = 'test';

        insert a;

        Event e1 = new Event();
        e1.WhatId = a.Id;
        e1.StartDateTime = DateTime.now().addMinutes(-90);
        e1.EndDateTime = DateTime.now().addMinutes(-45);

        insert e1;

        Event e2 = new Event();
        e2.WhatId = a.Id;
        e2.StartDateTime = DateTime.now().addMinutes(-80);
        e2.EndDateTime = DateTime.now().addMinutes(-70);

        Database.SaveResult res = Database.insert(e2,false);
        System.assertEquals('Overlap Session', res.getErrors()[0].getMessage());
    }
```